# What URL am I supposed to use in <video:player_loc> for my sitemap when adding a YouTube video?

Tags: seo, google-search, sitemap, youtube, video-sitemap

I'm somewhat confused. I'm following [this example](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/80471) on how to create video sitemap. So say, I need to add the `<video:video>` tag to my page's sitemap that contains this YouTube video:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dJT1jN2BtZk
```

I've come up with this so far:

```
<video:video>
    <video:player_loc allow_embed="yes">https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dJT1jN2BtZk</video:player_loc>
    <video:thumbnail_loc>https://img.youtube.com/vi/dJT1jN2BtZk/maxresdefault.jpg</video:thumbnail_loc>
    <video:title>Google dude giving generalities</video:title>
    <video:description>Some Google dude giving us basic generalities on how to do something. Not helpful at all.</video:description>
</video:video>
```

So question - did I fill in the `<video:player_loc>` tag correctly?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that you've filled in the `<video:player_loc>`tag correctly.

Comment: @NinaDubovich thanks. My only concern now is the `video:player_loc` tag. Which URL is it supposed to be `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dJT1jN2BtZk` or `https://www.youtube.com/embed/dJT1jN2BtZk`? if it even matters.

Comment: it should point to a player for a specific video, so /embed/

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Google Search documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/sitemaps/video-sitemaps), the `<video:player_loc>` tag should be used for Youtube's videos. Here's an example taken from our blog's sitemap:

```xml
<url>
  <loc>https://mailmeteor.com/blog/gmail-queued</loc>
  <lastmod>2022-12-20</lastmod>
  <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
  <video:video>
    <video:title>Why Gmail is queuing my emails?</video:title>
    <video:player_loc>https://www.youtube.com/embed/zbx4HZUZIwo</video:player_loc>
  </video:video>
</url>
```

As shown, you should use the `https://www.youtube.com/embed/...` URL, not the `watch?v=...` one.